# Routing traffic through compromised host

Tags: routing

I have a shell in a remote machine. I want to route my traffic in a dynamic way, so that can access say https://www.google.com via the IP address of the previously mentioned compromised machine.

I know you can route traffic to the internal network and access machines that otherwise have no connection to the outside. However, I want to know how one can use a compromised host as a proxy bounce of sorts.

Below is a rough sketch of how I want my traffic to go. `ip*` represents the visible public IP address.

```
Attacker machine[ip1] -> Victim machine[ip2] -> Outside network[ip2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for something called "pivoting". At least if you want to utilize the compromized host to further look into the attached network. There are quite a lot of ways to do it. One of them would be metasploit for example and you can read about it [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/pivoting/).

Other options include using SSH to forward your requests (see SSH-Portforwarding) but that only applies if SSH is present and only in a limited number of cases this is really useful. If you really do want to connect to a number of remote hosts through that machine I suggest either use metasploits routing or utilize a proxy server that you put on the server via your already existing shell.